# zone.tab file has disappeared causing the timezone to default to UTC

Tags: xubuntu, time, timezone

For whatever reason, the time on my Xubuntu 21.04 system has gone all awry and has defaulted to UTC. I cannot change the time as the time-admin program refuses to load with this error:

```
** (time-admin:26695): WARNING **: 15:03:13.124: Could not open */usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab*


** (time-admin:26695): ERROR **: 15:03:13.124: Unable to load system timezone database.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I haven't messed with any of these files manually (promise!). Maybe a faulty update or autoremove caused this?

In any case, how can I get timezones working again?

Comment: You may need to reconfigure the time zone data. If you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, are you able to set your correct time zone?

Comment: Nope! I reconfigured my timezone, and it just sticks to UTC. I even changed it to Australia as a test and it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by simply doing `apt install --reinstall tzdata`.